# Looping iterator until it's empty

Tags: java, iterator

I want to get all the objects from the list and put them into a `Map` grouped by creation date, which means the map is like this: `Map<String, List<MyObject>>`. The `MyObject` object has a field that stores its creation date.

I've thought of doing a nested while loop that looks like this:

```
public Map<String, List<Expense>> getExpensesSorted(SortType type){
    Map<String, List<Expense>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Expense>>();

    List<Expense> expenses = getAllExpenses(budgetId).getExpenses()
            .getList();

    if (type.equals(SortType.DAY)) {
        Iterator<Expense> expIter = expenses.iterator();

        while (expIter.hasNext()) {
            List<Expense> list = new ArrayList<Expense>();
            Expense exp = (Expense) expIter.next();
            list.add(exp);

            String day = exp.getDate().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            expIter.remove();

            while (expIter.hasNext()) {
                Expense exp2 = (Expense) expIter.next();
                if (exp2.getDate().format("YYYY-MM-DD").equals(day)) {
                    list.add(exp2);
                    expIter.remove();
                }
            }
            map.put(day, expenses);
        }

    } else if (type.equals(SortType.WEEK)) {
        ...
    } else if (type.equals(SortType.TYPE)) {
        ...
    } else if (type.equals(SortType.CATEGORY)) {
        ...
    }
    return map;
}
```

But this is wrong, it only gets all the ones that have the same day as the first element, so my map ends up having only one element.

I seriously don't know how to solve this...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job. I didn't compile it though.

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    MyObject obj = (MyObject) iter.next();
    String day = obj.getDate().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

    if(!map.containsKey(day)) {
       map.put(day, new ArrayList<MyObject>());
    }
    List<MyObject> list = map.get(day);
    list.add(obj);
    map.put(day, list);
}
```

Comment: That was a mistake on my part, it's the same `Iterator`

Comment: First I obtain the list for the given key, update the list by adding the new value without deleting the old ones and then overwrite the previous list corresponding with the key. Isn't it ok?

Comment: this is what I ended up doing, but without the iterator

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<Data, List<MyObject>> result = new HashMap<Data, List<MyObject>>;
for (List<MyObject> list : myMap.values()) {
    for (MyObject myObject : list) {
        Date date = myObject.getDate();
        List<MyObject> newList = result.get(date);
        if (newList == null) {
            newList = new Arraylist<MyObject>;
            result.put(date. newList);
        }
        newList.add(myObject);
    }
}
```